# Three-JS - Fullscreen change Size of renderer

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, fullscreen

I have made an ThreeJS application which is build to run in a 4:3 layout (there are many of buttons and so on). I would like to allow using Fullscreen via THREEx.Fullscreen.js. The Fullscreen mode is working, the problem I run into is, that the renderer.size(x,y) is changed into the screen size. Which is in my case a 16:9 layout.

So the question is, how to run ThreeJS fullscreen but still keep the renderer size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the display property of your canvas element as

```
canvas{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: well that was a fast response and a easy fix, thank you! I will accept your answer in 9 minutes (your answer was to fast, ha)

Comment: Pleasure to help

Comment: https://aboosbox.wordpress.com/2017/04/17/three-js-for-absolute-beginners/